# Загрузка файлов на сервер

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

У меня появилась проблема, не хочет доставать файл из временной папки... Происходит вот такая ошибка:

> `Warning: move_uploaded_file(/img/avatar/DSC00693.JPG) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u141735831/public_html/edit_photo.php on line 9`
>
> `Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpM8N5wQ' to '/img/avatar/DSC00693.JPG' in /home/u141735831/public_html/edit_photo.php on line 9`

Вот код обработчика:

```
<?php
    $uploads_dir = '/img/avatar';
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"];
    $name = $_FILES["filename"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно что ваш скрипт лежит в корне сайта, поэтому скорее всего так:

```
...
    $uploads_dir = './img/avatar'; 
...
```

- Если путь начинается с `/` то он считается от корня файловой системы
- Если путь начинается с `./`  - то от текущей папки
- Если с `../` - то с папки на уровень выше

И не забудьте установить права `+w` для загружающего пользователя на `$uploads_dir`, а то получите `Permission denied`

Comment: Спасибп, помогло)

Answer (score 2):

Ну первая ошибка ясно сообщает вам о том, что папка, в которую вы пытаетесь поместить файл, отсутствует или вы просто неправильно ввели её имя или путь к ней.
Вторая ошибка появляется в результате первой.

Comment: Нет, папка существует!

Comment: Ну может вы тогда просто ввели имя в нижнем регистре, а имя папки начинается с большой буквы? Вводите имя папки с ТОЧНЫМ соответствием регистра её имени. Если вы все делаете правильно, то может вы где-то забыли поставить "/" и в итоге имя файла слилось с путем?

Comment: А вы идете от корня FTP сервера?

Comment: путь полностью соответствует нужному...но вот почему то ошибка...
mysite.ru/img/avatar/ - это путь к папке

Comment: А можете показать весь код с первой по 15 строку? Так будет легче решить проблему.

Comment: если Вы про код оброботчика...то это всё что есть в файле...

есть файл который отправляет данные через post

<form action="/edit_photo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" align="center">
Загрузите фотографию профиля в формате .jpg<br>
<input type="file" name="filename" >
<div id="preview">Тут типо предпросмотр</div>
<br>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Сохранить">
</form>